# Sending callback and response in same function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it bad practice if I write response and callback in same function(here in A) as in case of parameter missing (!a|| !b), the response will be sent, but the parent context will not receive any callback, as a result, the API will dangle and memory would be wasted?

```
function practice (req, res){
    var a = req.body.a;
    var b = req.body.b;
    A(a,b, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }else{
            return res.send(c + "Action cmplete");
        }
    })
}

function A(a,b, callback){
  if(!a || !b){
      return res.send("param missing");
  }
  var c;
  c = a+b;
  return callback(null, c);
}
```

Comment: why not add an else loop after that if(!a || !b), that gives a callback with error..

Comment: Yes that could be done but I just want to know what will happen in my case @RajkumarSomasundaram

Comment: In ur case u are always invoking function A with 1,2 ; hence the if loop that u are taking about seems redundant to me.. also add " to your param missing line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code examples seem a bit incomplete since you don't even define `callbacka` anywhere.

But, in general, if you are designing a function that carries out some asynchronous operation and accepts a callback, then you will nearly always want to provide the caller with feedback when the asynchronous operation is complete with an error or complete successfully (and perhaps with a return value).  The only way to do that is to ALWAYS call the callback when the operation is done.

If you don't, then the caller simply never knows or has any way of knowing when the asynchronous operation is done and that is often (not always) a problem.  So, any general purpose asynchronous API that notifies via a callback should ALWAYS call the callback when the async operation is done.

Think about it from the caller's perspective.  The caller needs to know what to check for after making the function call.  You'd like to make their life simple and consistent.  If they were to check for everything, they'd have to check for a synchronous return value, a synchronous exception and check for whether the callback was called.  That's a nightmare of an API that requires all that.  You really want an API that just consistently uses ONE of those mechanisms.  So, if you're going to notify via a callback sometimes, then you should always notify via the callback and never use the other two mechanisms.

This is where promises come in for managing asynchronous operations because they can be even simpler.  Just always return a promise from your function and then the caller can just always use `.then()` and `.catch()` on the promise.  Your internal function then just either resolves or reject that promise.

---

On the other hand, if you want to design a function whose contract with the caller is that, under these conditions I'm going to execute some other code and not call the callback and under these other conditions I'm going to not execute that other code and call the callback instead, you can do that.  It's not a very consistent interface and it's not very friendly to a caller who is not very well versed in what you're doing, but you could do it.

I rather doubt you'd see an interface like that in a well known API because of the inconsistency.   But, you could do it for your own use if you really wanted.  I wouldn't consider it the best practice.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.I edited callback part.@jfriend00